# React always displays wrong Element

Tags: reactjs

```
 const [editable, setEditable] = useState([false,false,false]);

 { !editable[1] ? (
    <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleChange(1)} >EDIT </Button>
 ):(
    <Button variant="outlined" > Other buttons </Button>
 )}
```

Pretty simple trying to make an array of false values and then toggle between two displays no matter what I used for the tertany if gives me the bottom selection.

Comment: Hmmm. Try this `onClick={ () => { handleChange(1) } }`.

Comment: The problem usually is that if you pass a function with `()` at the end to onClick or onChange or whatever, it gets run while the code is being "read by the machine". Normally you would do `onClick={ handleChange }` but since you have an argument, you have to do it the way I showed at first.

Comment: Seems resolved. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const handleChange=(val)=>{
        if (val===1){
            setEditable([true, true, true])
        }
    }
{ !editable[1] ? (
                        <Button  onClick={()=>handleChange(1)} >EDIT </Button>
                    ):(
                        <Button > Other buttons </Button>
                    )}

//You should try this, you just need to toggle values on handle change
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks fine. The issue could be the fact that `editable[1]` is always `false`. Try to update the state. I am putting a little demo below.

#### [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/flamboyant-sound-l0fyd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Edit: As @mikaels-slava stated, the problem is probably caused by the `onClick={handleChange(1)}` part. Since you send the function, not running it. You should change it to `onClick={() => handleChange(1)}`.

Comment: Second glance at my comment haha